# How to add a physics body to each frame of a sprite sheet?

Tags: sprite, coronasdk, physics

Let's say I have a Sprite Sheet of a character in a game. There are 4 frames of him walking to the right direction, his shape changing in each frame. How do I define the shape for each individual frame when I add a physics body to this sprite?

I'm under the impression that I have to split the sprite sheet into individual images and define the shape for each image, but if that's the case I don't know what to do from there, programming-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have different physics bodies for each frame of a sprite.  You can try to get it close for most of the frames.  If you choose to go the separate frame route, you will have to write your own animation function to animate the sprites.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't try to do that. It'll completely kill your physics simulation.

The problem with it is that the mass of a shape is calculated from its area. If you have a character animation - e.g. walking, swinging his - he would gain weight when the arms are stretched and loose weight when the arms are next to the body.

Try not to be too exact about the collision shapes - the player usually won't see the difference anyways. Just make it good enough.

One option is to approximate the shape by using a union or intersection of your animation frames.

Take a look at this tutorial - it's for cocos2d - but the physics shape creation section is basically the same for corona.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/33525/how-to-build-a-monkey-jump-game-using-cocos2d-2-x-physicseditor-texturepacker-part-1

Near the center is a more detailed explanation how to create collision shapes for animations.